# Updating state in SwiftUI closure "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this UIViewControllerRepresentable with a @Binding which is a bool that determines if the view is in "Selection Mode" or not. I have a closure in the View Controller in order to update the selection mode state to false when everything is deselected. However, I'm getting the warning "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior" when I set `isInSelectionMode = false` in the closure. I understand you don't want to update state that the View depends on during rendering, but I don't see how this is doing that.

```
struct ExampleView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isInSelectionMode: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ExampleViewController {
        let exampleViewController = ExampleViewController()
        exampleViewController.onDeselectAll = {
            isInSelectionMode = false     // Warning occurs here
        }
        return exampleViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ExampleViewController, context: Context) { }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you wrap that line in `Task { @MainActor in ... }`?

Comment: @jnpdx That seems to have gotten rid of the warning! But why?

Comment: Because without it, your `isInSelectionMode` was getting set on the same run loop as the render of the `View`. My suggestion moves it to the next run loop.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement update, e.g.

```
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: StickerPickerController, context: Context) { 
    exampleViewController.onDeselectAll = nil
    exampleViewController.selectionMode = isInSelectionMode
    exampleViewController.onDeselectAll = {
        isInSelectionMode = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I was still getting the warning when placing it in updateUIViewController